# Action Cable: Notify a single user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I am building a chat application in which users can chat privately. I am stuck at the following point:

- 'User A' clicks on 'User B' s chat icon, now we need to send a notification to a single 'User B'. How can one achieve this?
- 'User A' has N number of friends. When 'User A' goes offline, how do one notify only the N number of friends in the system?

So in general, how to send a notification to a limited number of connected users?

Answer (score 2):

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    identified_by :uuid

    def connect
      # feel free to use any methods to store and match this
      # uuid with current user
      self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end
  end
```

Then in any part of your app:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast user_uuid, data
```